# Tool to edit MS word document via web application and process via server

Tags: microsoft-word, word-processor

Has anyone used or are using a web-based tool that can edit word documents that has a library/SDK so I can use it within my application? Essentially I need Office365 Word within my application.

I would be happy for the user to see the word document, make edits and the new changes to be processed on a server. If I can do versions and comments that would be even better.

I have seen something that can do markdown to word and in reverse.

I am happy to use paid and opensource.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean in JavaScript? Or is it OK to perform the edit server-side? If the latter, on your own server or is it OK to use a third-party paid service?

Comment: Should the library let the human user edit the document visually? Or would your program only perform some automatic edits (for instance replacing "hello <USER>" by "hello nicolas"), and the user would just download the resulting file?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify, then ask us to reopen. Thanks :-)

Comment: Could you please improve the title too? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Apache POI : https://poi.apache.org

PHP Javabridge example: https://gist.github.com/motin/6115683

PHPWord: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

LiveDocx: Zend supported https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zendservice.livedocx.html

Their own SDK: https://docs.reporting.cloud/docs/chapter/sdks/php

References:

1. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bf0fd90d-1e50-4a18-ba5c-c7a541e71d2a/office-365-integration-in-php-web-application?forum=accessdev

Answer (score 1):

[Syncfusion Document Editor](https://www.syncfusion.com/aspnet-core-ui-controls/word-processor) can be used to display and create/edit Word documents in web applications with a .NET/Core backend: [Live Sample](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/demos/#/material/document-editor/default.html).

[image: Syncfusion Document Editor]

The entire product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue). The community license is the full product with no limitations.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Hey, the only issue with this I had is that they didn't have a PHP library for the backend which is my prefered stack. But it did look good, maybe I might revisit it.